# jquery how to break string and continue string after

Tags: php, jquery

im trying to do this to get loop i variable inside my php variable

```
var monthyear[i] = "<?php echo $startmonth_name"+i+" ?>";
```

so it will show like:

```
 var monthyear[i] = "<?php echo $startmonth_name1 ?>";
 var monthyear[i] = "<?php echo $startmonth_name2 ?>";
```

can't figure it out and i keep getting error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'
```

Comment: You cannot mix javascript and PHP in the manner you are attempting as JS is client side, and PHP is server side. In other words, the PHP has finished executing LONG before any JS is run. The best way to mix the two is to use AJAX to retrieve the values you need from PHP after the page has loaded.

Comment: yes, i have these working without the loop but i want to shorten my code..

Comment: So, you need to store the $startmonth_name{N} in an array and loop on this last... (no JS needed)

Comment: Where is `i` coming from, or more accurately, can it be transfered to a loop in PHP with `$i`

Comment: i think there is too much thought going into this... var monthyear[i] = "test"+i;  will show no error... i just need to know how to break the string and readd it... "....."+"...." but that doesnt work with my php echo

Comment: @rubberchicken it won't work with the loop because the loop is iterated only long after your php code is executed. `i` value in your first line is javascript variable but php will try to fetch value of `i` which it can't.

Comment: really? aw i thought it would simply just work! ok thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop in javascript won't work for reasons mentioned in my comment, you can try having a loop in php code, something like below.

Replace this with

```
var monthyear[i] = "<?php echo $startmonth_name1 ?>";
var monthyear[i] = "<?php echo $startmonth_name2 ?>";
```

With

```
<?php 

for($i=0;$i<some_value;$i++)
{
   echo "var monthyear[".$i."] = ". ${'startmonth_name'.$i} .";"
}

?>
```

Note: I haven't tested the code. This is just to give an idea.

Answer (score 1):

do this instead:

```
<?php echo "var monthyear["+i+"] = '"+ $startmonth_name[i]+"';"; ?>;
```

change these to an array to use them in the loop:  $startmonth_name1

Answer (score 0):

Forget about JavaScript right now. JavaScript will be executed later, in another computer, possibly some thousand kilometres away. You are getting a PHP parse error: that means that your PHP code does not even run. And it's clear why—the PHP block contained in this code:

```
var monthyear[i] = "<?php echo $startmonth_name"+i+" ?>";
```

... is this:

```
echo $startmonth_name"+i+"
```

You might get away with something like this:

```
var monthyear[i] = <?php echo json_encode($startmonth_name); ?>+i;
```

Yet I suggest you remember that PHP and JavaScript will simply neither interact nor share variables and rethink your logic accordingly.